# Set of polynomials a subspace of P3?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Is the set of all polynomials of the form $a_0+a_1x$, where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are real numbers a subspace of $P_3$?

My book says it is not.

Both closure under addition and scalar multiplication hold, so I don't understand why.
And if $P_3$ is taken to mean the set of all polynomials with degree $3$ or less then I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: By the way, my book might be wrong. If you think it is, please tell me.

Comment: Hmmm. Is it possible that they are stipulating $a_{0}\neq 0$? In this case, your set does not contain the zero vector (namely the constant function $0$), so it is not a subspace. Otherwise, I'd be inclined to agree that your book is wrong, and your set is the subspace $P_{1} \subset P_{3}$. I could be missing something too, though.

Comment: @AWertheim But in that case they wouldn't have said that for part (a) where the set of polynomials is of the form a0+a1x+a2x^2+a3x^3, where a1=a2, is a subspace of P3 right?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow. That's indeed a subspace as well, as long as they do not require $a_{0} \neq 0$. If you're suggesting that if $a_{0} \neq 0$ is not a requirement in part (a), hence it is probably not a requirement here, you may be right. I was just offering a suggestion as to what their reasoning might be.

Comment: @AWertheim Yes that is what I was saying. Thank you. So you think it is a mistake? Because if that is the case, then this book is making a ridiculous amount of mistakes!

Comment: I think so, unless you and I have both missed something here (which isn't impossible, of course ;) ). I'm sorry to hear your book has so many mistakes. But it looks to me you've got a solid grasp of things nonetheless. :)

Comment: Does $a_1$ have a stipulation to be non-zero?

Comment: @GFauxPas No it doesn't based on the answers for the other parts of the same question.

Comment: @AWertheim Thank you! That is very encouraging to hear!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the set of all polynomials of the form $a_0+a_1x$ is indeed a subspace of $\mathcal{P}_3(\mathbf R)$ since it fulfills all the necessary criteria for being a subspace,

1. It contains the $0$ vector.
2. It is closed under addition, $(a_0+a_1x)+(b_0+b_1x)=(a_0+a_1)+(b_0+b_1)x$ which is in that set.
3. It is closed under scalar multiplication, $\lambda(a_0+a_1x)=(\lambda a_0)+(\lambda a_1)x$ which is in that set.